# When to use Fury?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just got Skyrim today and I am confused by an ability. I am playing as a high elf mage and I have got the Fury skill but cannot figure out when I would use it. Can anyone explain to me when and why this spell is useful?

Comment: Playing same class/race combo myself.  I'm up past level 30 now, and haven't used Fury (or a number of other spells, for that matter) once.

Comment: The illusion spell tree feels best used with sneak. Silent casting, invisibility, muffle etc. Illusion works incredibly well (I use it on my Khajit assassin). People underestimate it because it doesn't create big explosions.

Comment: is fury the same as frenzy then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fury is good for areas with multiple enemies. You cast fury on a single target, making sure you don't get seen doing it. The victim will then start attacking nearby allies, usually until someone dies. Bear in mind they will attack you if they see you first.

Comment: Fury poison on arrows is loads of fun. =D

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So it sounds like I would mainly use Fury if I was sneaking. That's not really my way of playing Skyrim, though I am glad to know what the ability is for. It confused me a lot.

Answer (score 7):

Fury (like Calm) will interrupt the current action, such as a power swing.

While Fury can cause the target to choose to attack opponents other than you, it can also cause other opponents to choose to attack the target instead of you.

Consider this scenario:  Bob, Jim and Mark are bandits.  They see and attack you.  You cast fury on the closest one (Bob).  Bob stops his current power swing and must wind up a new one.  He happens to attack you (bummer).  Jim and Mark see that Bob is emotionally unstable, and are now as eager to attack him as attack you - and Bob is closer.  Jim and Mark attack Bob.

It gets even better if the bandits don't see you.

Comment: That's smart. I will definitely try to use it like you said. Though by all the answers and comments it seems that Fury is mainly usable if you like to sneak. That's not really the way I play Skyrim. I enjoy going head first with my Flame.

Answer (score 1):

Well I use it during my assassinations to get the target to attack someone and get killed.

An example: I felt like killing Nazeem in Whiterun so I hid and used fury on him. Nazeem then attacks everyone and they all just kill him.

Answer (score 1):

Fury is like forcing someone to fight for their life, even killing *allies*(they will attack the furied person) use it when sneaking to get someone assassinated, or if your feeling cruel, have a brawl on the street to wipe out entire cities(of non-essentials of course)or, if  your me, cause riots......and make a huge pile of dead bodies(still non essentials)